# Ideal OneDrive client for syncing save data/small files, without fully downloading everything

Tags: sync

I'm looking to sync game saves from yuzu (as well as other stuff like ssh configs etc.) between multiple OSes/Devices using OneDrive.

Namely I would need to sync Windows, Ubuntu, as well as Steam OS (Arch, afaik?).

I'm already set up to do this with Windows. My current solution is to just create a junction from the folder to OneDrive (e.g. %userprofile%\.ssh -> %OneDriveFolder%\AppData\.ssh). Then I set this folder to be offline available (always keep on device).
It automatically syncs in the background and I don't have to worry about it at all.

My issue is that I don't know a good onedrive client for Linux, that has the features of the windows client.
I use rclone on my servers, but it basically just mounts like a network share, and isn't properly available offline (at least I wasn't able to figure out how to set that up.)

I would need a way to keep files offline available, automatic background sync (although I could also just crontab it worst case...), as well as the possibility to exclude folders from being always downloaded (or just excluded from sync) as I have my off-site backups in OneDrive, and I don't feel like downloading a couple hundred gigs on every device.

I could probably bodge something together, but I would prefer a solution that is actually reliable.

Does anybody know a great client that I could check out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know a great client that I could check out?

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

There are 5 reliable ways to access OneDrive on Linux/Unix platforms:

- Via the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive - this 'syncs' your data, bi-directional operation, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business & SharePoint account types and Shared Folders. A Docker container is also available for all major architectures (i686, x86_64, ARMHF, AARCH64). If you need a GUI for onedrive client management use: https://github.com/bpozdena/OneDriveGUI
- Via the 'onedriver' client - https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver - Native file system that only provides the OneDrive 'on-demand' functionality, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business account types. Currently does not support Shared Folders or SharePoint.
- Via 'rclone' - https://rclone.org/ - one way sync client, open source and free. Has limitations with SharePoint.
- Via non-free clients such as 'insync', 'ExpanDrive'
- Via the web browser of your choice

> as well as the possibility to exclude folders from being always downloaded (or just excluded from sync)

Specific to this item, please read: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/onedrive-v2.5.0-alpha-4/docs/usage.md#using-client-side-filtering-rules-to-determine-what-should-be-synced-with-microsoft-onedrive

Whilst this is part of the documentation set for 'alpha-4' there is nothing new in the functionality being described that is not part of the current latest available release.

Comment: Hi your client looks really good! Seems to tick all the requirements I've listed. One more question though, does it have the "on demand" feature of onedrive, where you can open a file and have it automatically download, even if excluded from sync? I'm assuming not, as it mostly just downloads and syncs the files directly?

Comment: Thank you for your kind words about the client! To answer your question, the client I maintain currently doesn't offer the 'on-demand' feature similar to OneDrive, where files are automatically downloaded upon opening even if they're not synced. This limitation is also mentioned in the documentation. If this feature is crucial for you, you might consider exploring jstaf's onedriver. It supports this functionality, though it's important to note that it has some limitations regarding Microsoft OneDrive account support and may not have all the features provided by the client I maintain.